# Column used in the publication WHERE expression is not part of the replica identity

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, postgresql-15

I'm trying to create a logical replication setup where I have a single large database with smaller read replicas branching of filtered on a sub id.

For example, if I wanted a subset of items pushed to read replicas for a specific customer, I might have a table on the replication node defined by:

```
CREATE TABLE public.item (
       id text PRIMARY KEY, 
       data text, 
       customer_id integer
       );
```

I may or may not have `sub_id` on the subscription node (not a deal breaker detail). On the replication node, I can add data to the table as I please **until** I create the PUBLICATION like so:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION customer_items FOR TABLE public.item (
       id, 
       data
       ) WHERE (customer_id = 3);
```

At this point, I try something like

```
UPDATE public.item SET
    customer_id = 3 WHERE 
    id = 'GLAMDRING';
```

I get the error I get an `SQL state: 42P10` error, or..:

```
ERROR:  cannot update table "item"
DETAIL:  Column used in the publication WHERE expression is not part of the replica identity.
STATEMENT: UPDATE public.item SET
    customer_id = $1::integer WHERE 
    id = 'GLAMDRING';
```

The issue [here looks similar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/330758/252703). I've recreating the table to remove any ALTER TABLE statements on `id`, as suggested there, but I have the same result.

Most examples I can find that use this logical replication function never make use of the WHERE clause. I'm thinking I've either misunderstood the meaning behind this feature, or I've found a bug/limitation.

**Please note:** I am aware that my example seems trivial and should be solved some other way. This is a simplified version of my problem for the sake of brevity.

---

**Update**

Trying to use Unique index, as suggested almost got me there.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_customerid_idx ON public.item ((customer_id || id));
```

But when I try creating a useful PUBLICATION..

```
CREATE PUBLICATION customer_items FOR TABLE public.item (id, data) WHERE (customer_id || id LIKE '3%');
```

New error:

```
ERROR:  User-defined or built-in mutable functions are not allowed.invalid publication WHERE expression 

ERROR:  invalid publication WHERE expression
SQL state: 0A000
Detail: User-defined or built-in mutable functions are not allowed.
Character: 377
```

Maybe my use-case is a little wild or I need to rethink my application logic to work with these constraints. Am I missing an obvious work around here?

Comment: I guess you should create a unique index on `(id, customer_id)` and use that as the replica identity for the table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks! For my use-case seems I need a user defined function, which aren't allowed (see update).

Comment: "Trying to use Unique index, as suggested" -- that's now what was suggested though, why are you concatenating the columns? Have you tried exactly `create index ... (id, customer_id)`? With that index, set as the replica identity for the table, your original publication row filter should work.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, I tried the `create index.. (id, customer_id)` syntax first. Same/similar error. I'm guessing the query planner may be deciding to use only one indexed column.
I've tried a few ways of attacking this and none get me there.Will try a few more permutations.

Comment: Should mention that this is AWS RDS. Didn't think it would matter, but in case it does...

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong, but the approach works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/-DVUFpLp

Comment: Used your exact commands and same error! Using Postgres 15 on dbfiddle works too..... So looks like an AWS issue...?
Will try upgrading to 16 on RDS next.

Comment: Work with AWS RDS 16.1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Working As Designed™](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createpublication.html)

> A row filter expression (i.e., the `WHERE` clause) must contain only columns that are covered by the `REPLICA IDENTITY`, in order for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations to be published.

I think the restriction is there to accommodate the `UPDATE` transformations:

> Whenever an `UPDATE` is processed, the row filter expression is evaluated for both the old and new row

where "old" and "new" are the replica identity values, so the filter column must be a part of them.

Comment: RTFM, doh! Think I would have missed this implementation detail of how UPDATE works under the hood, even if I had found that line.